# Convergence of certain sequences in $\Bbb R^\omega$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ be the countable product of $\mathbb{R}$. Make it a topological space using the box topology. Let $\pi_{k}$ denote the usual projection maps.

Define $A_N = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^\omega \mid \forall k>N: \pi_{k}(x) = 0\}$. Suppose that for some $N$, all elements in a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ are in $A_N$ and that for any $k$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \pi_{k}(x_n) =0$. Show that the sequence then converges to $(0,0,0, \ldots).$

My thought process: I know that a given sequence $\{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ such that each $x_n$ is in $X$, $\{x_n\}$ converges to x if for any open set $U \subset X$ containing $x$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $x_n \in U$ whenever $n>N$. In addition, I noted that as long as $k>N$, $\pi_{k}(x_n)$ will be $0$. Not really sure how to show to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The subspace $A_N$ of $\Bbb R^\omega$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^N$ with the usual product topology; the homeomorphism is a very simple, natural one.

**Added:** Let $z=\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$; you have to show that if $U$ is any open nbhd of $z$, then there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_\ell\in U$ whenever $\ell\ge m$. Without loss of generality you may assume that there are positive real numbers $\epsilon_k$ for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $U=\prod_{k\ge 1}(-\epsilon_k,\epsilon_k)$. (Why?)

Suppose that $1\le k\le n$. Then the sequence $\langle\pi_k(x_\ell):\ell\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $0$, so there is an $m_k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|\pi_k(x_\ell)|<\epsilon_k$ whenever $n\ge m_k$. Let $m=\max\{m_k:k=1,\ldots,n\}$, and explain why $x_\ell\in U$ for all $\ell\ge m$.

Comment: Am I looking for a function? If so, is it $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: You don’t actually need to find any function once you see what’s really going on. Seeing that, however, amounts to seeing how $A_N$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^N$, which I suppose means seeing what the homeomorphism is, and it’s a function from one of $A_N$ and $\Bbb R^N$ to the other. Try looking at the special case $N=1$; can you see why $A_1$ is really just like $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, because if N=1, then for any k>1, then $\pi_{k}(x)=0$. However, the 1st coordinate can be anything, which implies that it can be homeomorphic $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Right. And $A_2$ has only two ‘live’ coordinates, so it looks just like $\Bbb R^2$. If you have a sequence of points in $\Bbb R^N$ such that every coordinate is approaching $0$, does the sequence converge to the zero vector?

Comment: Yes, because then you have zero 'live' coordinates.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: No, all $N$ coordinates are live in the sense in which I was using the term: they’re not **forced** to be $0$, as the $x_k$ for $k>N$ are in $A_N$. But you’re right that the sequence converges to the zero vector. Now just transfer the proof of that fact to $A_N$: show that every open nbhd of the zero function in $A_N$ contains a tail of the sequence.

Comment: Can you say that since $A_N$ of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^N}$ with the usual product topology and that every open neighborhood of the zero function in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ contains a tail of the sequence, then by the definition of a homeomorphism so does $A_{N} \text{in} \mathbb{R}^\omega$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Yes, but if you do it that way, you must describe the homeomorphism and prove that it is one. The alternative of adapting the proof in $\Bbb R^N$ to $A_N$ is likely to be shorter.

Comment: Is this what you looking for? Since $A_N$ will always have coordinates that are not forced to be 0; each open neighborhood hood of the zero function in $A_N$ will contain a tail of the sequence. However, because every coordinate is approaching 0, the sequence will converge to the zero vector just as it had in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Just work directly with the definition of convergence of a sequence. Let $U$ be an arbitrary open nbhd of the zero function; without loss of generality we may assume that $U$ is an open box $\prod_kU_k$, where each $U_k$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$ that contains $0$, say $U_k=(-\epsilon_k,\epsilon_k)$. Now use the fact that each coordinate sequence approaches $0$ to show that there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in U$ for all $n\ge m$.

Comment: Wouldn't m=k then?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: ??? There is no specific $k$ in my comment: $k$ appears only as a dummy variable running over the indices of the factor spaces, so it has no specific value.

Comment: I think I have the solution. Because each coordinate sequence is approaching 0, the sequence is approaching the 0 vector. As a result, there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq m$.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: You need to give more of a justification than that. **Why** is there such an $m$? How do you know?

Comment: Because if you make $U=(-\infty, \infty)$ or any open interval on the real line smaller than this so that it contains 0, all values of $\{x_n\} \in U$ since they are all 0

Comment: @KangHoonYou: But that $U$ isn’t even a subset of your space! I’m not sure exactly where you’re going astray, but I don’t think that we’re going to sort it out in comments. I’m going to expand my answer a bit.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: What’s $x$? The zero sequence $z\in U$ for that reason, but we knew that to begin with: we chose $U$ to be a nbhd of $z$. You need to show that $x_\ell\in U$ whenever $\ell\ge m$.

Comment: Does the answer have to do with the amount of 'live' variables?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: What’s crucial is that there are only finitely many of them, and I already used that fact when I let $m=\max\{m_k:k=1,\ldots,n\}$. At this point I’m honestly at a bit of a loss to know what else to say, because the addition to my answer already does most of the work.

Comment: Oh! Is it because since there are only finitely many live variables, and the rest of them are converging to 0, then $x_l \in U$ because every $x_l$ will then have to contain a tail of the sequence.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: The rest of them **are** $0$. Suppose that $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. If $\ell\ge m$, then by the definition of $m$ we know that $\ell\ge m_k$. What does this say about $\pi_k(x_\ell)$?

Comment: They are all 0 coordinates.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: There is no reason to think so: $k$ is one of the $n$ coordinates that **don’t** have to be $0$.

Comment: It converges to 0. And it is in the neighborhood U.